Restore Separate Boot, one drive for windows, one drive for Linux
Hardware Setup
I have 2 hard drives
Let's name them

"Drive 1" is an 1TB nvme
"Drive 2" is a 500GB SSD

Software Setup

Drive 1 where windows is installed.
Drive 2 where I installed Linux Mint like two days ago

Important info >:
Even though I really specified during the installation process of Linux Mint that I want Linux Mint to be installed entirely on Drive2, it apparently destroyed the Windows boot.
What do I mean by "destroyed the Windows Boot"
I mean that now, I have a working dual boot with Grub, and sure I can boot Windows from there
But, if I specifically choose Drive1 in the BIOS to boot from -> boom I get the good old message: "insert bootable disk"
My question is therefore the following:
How do I restore TWO SEPARATE boots on my computer?
So that i am the one who chooses which drive I boot from in the bios
In other words HOW do I restore the normal windows boot on Drive 1 without impacting Drive 2?
To be clear

Yes, I do not want to use a Grub/dual boot thing every time I start my computer
Yes, I want to be the one who chooses manually which drive my computer boots from
It may be odd but this is the way I feel comfy with my computer.
And yes, this question may seem like it's been covered many times -> it's not. My case, is apparently relatively specific: I don't want to use Grub, I want to manually operate my dual boot. And this is apparently a very weird case :')

EDIT:

You can see that Linux Mint has decided to mount that partition as /boot/efi which is NOT what I asked for during the installation process (see next screenshot)

You can see here that small partition of 1GB? That should have been the EFI partition that Linux Mint was supposed to use. NOw I realize that I should have put that partition "in front of the other partitions", as in: it should be the first partition on disk.

When installing OSes to separate drives, it's recommended to install boot partitions for each OS on both drives. Normally, this is as simple as running from WinPE/WinRE BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD (UEFI would use a BcdBoot command in lieu of && BootRec /FixBoot), however when dual-booting Linux, BootRec will overwrite GRUB. There's a Linux package that can recreate the BCD Store on Windows' boot partition, however you'll still need to create the boot partition first, then the boot files with BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f <BIOS|UEFI>

(Cont'd...) Boot partition: Y: | OS partition: C: is usually not the OS partition in WinPE/WinRE (I'm unsure if BcdBoot will overwrite GRUB, so be prepared to fix GRUB just in case). Get the boot and OS partition mount points via: DiskPart → lis vol → exit

@JW0914 thank you for your answers and info. I have added screenshots to my original question.  It's ok if I need to reinstall Linux after restoring Windows bootloader. Particularly because I think I did a mistake -> the small partition on "drive2" (2nd screenshot) that I planned to use as /boot/efi should be the first partition on the drive I guess?

nvme0 has the right partition order, sda2 doesn't - boot partition needs to be first, unsure if swap needs to go before or after the OS partition, but the OS install man pages will tell you. You want partitions like boot and MSR to be at the front of a drive because they'll never be touched and when resizing partitions, the free space comes from the end of the partition. It would be recommended to create equally sized EFI partitions on both drives that are 850MB each, then configure each as the boot partition for both OSes (with Windows, copy over all the files and rebuild the BCD Store)

(Cont'd...) When dual-booting Linux, different distros want different EFI partition sizes for some reason, with the largest I've come across being ~750MB. Windows requires a 100MB boot partition, so I always recommend summing both, which should prevent any issues should you choose to install more than one distro or switch to a different distro (not planning ahead like this creates an inconvenience down the road since it would then require partitions having to be moved to get free space next to the boot partition)

@JW0914 thank again <3, I have restored Windows' bootloader. Im gonna try to do things right this time, and try to follow your advice. If I got it right -> on my Drive 2 (sda2), I'll just remove everything, and pay attention to create a sufficiently big /boot partition at the BEGINNING of the disk. That should do the trick. And hopefully, Linux Mint won't scratch my Windows bootloader again. Also, I have written a long tutorial below, it's possible to feel that I was a little "nervous" writing it, in no way this is in response to your help -> you were super helpful <3

So here is what I had to do:
Important: this solution messes up Grub, but that's fine for my needs.

Access WinRE, which is short for Windows Recovery Environment (I don't like acronyms when they're not needed)
But Windows Recovery Environment was not "fully" available on my computer, because when I run Reagentc.exe /info it says the Recovery Environment is disabled
I tried to enable it with this command Reagentc.exe /enable but it did not work. Something was missing.

Windows Recovery Environment is not really available on your PC?
I'm gonna try to be COMPLETE, accurate, precise and honest, so no skipping steps!

My solution was to: find my Windows ISO install file. If you don't have that ISO file -> you can download one from Microsoft website as far as I know.
Mount the ISO file (right click on it, Windows 10 offers that option)
Go in the sources/ directory in that mounted iso file
Find install.esd, I created a directory called Images in C:\Images, and I copied install.esd there
Now you're gonna want to CONVERT that C:\Images\install.esd file into an C:\Images\install.wim file, so for further reference your install.esd file is located in C:\Images, you do the conversion with this command (in a PowerShell that you open with administrator permission (start menu -> type "powershell" -> right click -> run as administrator)): dism /export-image /SourceImageFile:install.esd /SourceIndex:2 /DestinationImageFile:install.wim /Compress:max /CheckIntegrity
Don't close PowerShell yet
In the same PowerShell come back to C:\ (do as much cd.. as needed), then type mkdir mount
Now you need to mount your newly created install.wim: Dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:C:\Images\install.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:"C:\mount"
In case this does not work -> open your explorer and right click on the "mount" folder -> properties -> and uncheck the "read only" thingy and apply and press ok. You can also do that with a command line such as attrib -h -r -s C:\Mount\Windows\System32\Recovery\*.* /s /d good luck with that though
Ok, anyway, now if you're lucky you have mounted install.wim in the mount directory
In your explorer go to C:\mount\Windows\System32\Recovery and there should be a file called Winre.wim, the holy grail, the golden nugget here it is
Let's go, now you must do this: copy Winre.wim to your desktop or wherever you'll be able to retrieve it later on
You can try to unmount the previously mounted install.wim Dism.exe /UnMount-Image /MountDir:C:\mount /Commit but honestly? It doesn't matter.
Check that the Windows Recovery Environment is indeed disabled, I mean at this point it's pretty sure it is, still in the same PowerShell windows as before: Reagentc.exe /Disable /target C:\windows
Still in PowerShell, at the root of your C:\ (do as much as cd.. as needed, create a directory called "recovery"
Copy the Winre.rim file inside this newly created directory
Same as before with the explorer or with a command line -> right click on that directory -> properties -> uncheck the read only option and apply it to everything included in that directory
Then in PowerShell you can do: Reagentc.exe /SetReImage /path C:\recovery\ /Target C:\Windows
Reagentc.exe /enable 
Reagentc.exe /enable /target C:\windows 
Reagentc.exe /info /target C:\windows 
You can Go to Star menu -> type "Update" -> then on the left panel you should see something called "recovery" -> click on restart now -> your computer is gonna...make you wait
Then before rebooting it'll display a series of options -> do this: Troubleshoot -> Advanced options -> Command Prompt
Now your computer is gonna reboot
After reboot, it's gonna ask you to select the user account you wanna use and enter the password corresponding to that account
Then FINALLY we have a command line

Oh but wait, you think you're done?
You think you're gonna be able to use bootrec /fixmbr or bootrec /scanos? Nope, you cannot.
If like me you got the error "cannot find the file specified" to all those command then you need to do this

In the command line of the Windows Recovery Environment type: diskpart
Then list disk
Then select disk <here put a number that corresponds to the disk where windows is installed> (for me it was select disk 1)
Then select partition <here you put the number of the partition where windows is installed, it's usually the BIGGEST partition on the select disk > for me it was (select partition 3)
Then you can type active and you'll get probably an mbr related error message -> don't worry it's fine
now you type exit
You're out of diskpart now, you can type: bcdboot.exe C:\windows
you can type exit and reboot your computer

NOW YOU ARE DONE
Yes this solution messes up Grub, but that's fine for my needs. I'm going to reinstall Linux and really pay attention to the partition order and where Linux Mint installs the /boot/efi partition
Sources:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avSQ0GnRvj0
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-download-winrewim/e4ea068c-590a-4c8d-8498-1d79cbec1acc
And an infinite amount of google searches and forum pages where people throw random command lines :')


Funny part of the story? After doing all that, I get to have now TWO bootloaders on the SAME drive (Drive 1 in my original post). And I can choose (from BIOS) between the two. One bootloader -> loads Windows, the other one loads Grub -> which gives me the choice again between Windows and Linux. I wanted to install those on TWO separate disks, but honestly? I think that's ok now, I'll keep it like it. Let's not try to fix what's working.

Please note that this is a professional site. We expect the language used on this site to be professional.

@music2myear sure, sure. Thanks for the edits on my answer. I wonder how my answer already got down voted without much reads though.
